# How to use gauss law in a space of uniform charge density?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Lets say there is a uniform charge density throughout the entire space. At any point $P$, if I consider shells entered at $P$, the field at that point will be zero because according to Gauss Law, field inside a shell is zero.

But If I consider shells which are not centered at $P$, then the field is non zero. Why are the answers different?

Comment: If there is an uniform charge density everywhere then there will be an electric field. Every surface you will consider will contain some charge and thus you will have a non-zero flux on that surface.

Comment: The field inside *an empty shell* is zero.   Your shells will have charge in them.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39654/

Comment: An infinite uniformly charged  universe is mathematically inconsistent with Coulomb's law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There no unique solution to the problem you pose. The field inside a "uniform" charge distribution depends on what is going on far far away on the distant surface.