# Infinite, straight, current-carrying wire uniformly charged to a negative electrostatic potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

I am working on a problem that states the following:

> Imagine an infinite straight wire carrying a current $I$ and uniformly
>   charged to a negative electrostatic potential $\phi$

I know here that the current $I$ will set up a magnetic field around the wire that abides to the right hand rule with magnitude:

$
B(r) = \frac{I\mu_0}{2\pi r}.
$

However, what is the importance of there being a negative electrostatic potential $\phi$? Does this mean that the wire sets up an electrostatic  $\vec{E}$ field in addition to the magnetic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would have to know the rest of the problem to be sure, but most likely it means what you say. A wire connected to a DC source will in fact have a current going through it and it will be at some nearly uniform potential. If we wanted to solve Laplace's equation to find the potential everywhere, the wire would work as a boundary condition.

Comment: I found that the potential should be of the form:
$
V(r) = C_1 \ln(r) + C_0
$

but then how am I supposed to apply the boundary condition that at $r=0, V(r) = \phi$ ? Should I assume instead that at some $r_0 \ne 0$ that $V(r_0) = \phi$, meaning that the wire has some finite width?

Comment: @Loonuh: That would be one way to do it, though you still can't impose a boundary condition at infinity. The problem here (see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24155/infinitely-charged-wire-and-differential-form-of-gauss-law) for more details) is that the potential for this wire is not well defined. If the problem asks you to find the potential everywhere, then it's a badly-posed problem.