# a point charge above an infnite not-grounded plate

Tags: electrostatics

A famous example of the method of image charges is a point charge above an infinite **grounded** plate. Can we use the method if the plate is not grounded?

**My thoughts:** The conductor's surface is equipotential otherwise the current starts to flow. And at the infinity we assume that potential must be zero. It means that an infinite not-grounded plate always have zero potential (with respect to a point at infinity)

Comment: *"And at the infinity we assume that potential must be zero."* - careful; for this, we ordinarily assume the system is bounded so that one can get arbitrarily far away.  Consider, [for example](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24155/infinitely-charged-wire-and-differential-form-of-gauss-law#comment55924_24155), the potential for an infinitely long wire with non-zero charge.

Comment: no, the potential of the plate is non zero for any finite distance of the charge.

Comment: @Lelouch, non zero comparing to which point?